# Can I configure Spring JMS to send custom errors to a queue/topic?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I have a Spring JMS project and I need to catch certain types of Exceptions, convert them to an Error object, and then send them to a custom destination. I could use a try/catch as shown below and this should work, but I would like to know if there is a Spring class out there that I can use where I can put this kind of code, so that it is out of the way. I was looking at the `ErrorHandler` Interface which looks promising, but I need some of the headers that come in from the inbound request, which is not suitable for the `handleError(Throwable t)` method. Any suggestions, or thoughts are very much appreciated!

```
    ...
    public void onMessage(Message<AnObject> inboundMsg, Map<String,Object> headers){
        try{
            someServiceCall(inboundMsg);
        }catch(SomeException se){
            AnError error = convertToError(se);
            jmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("error-destination",error,headers);
        }
    }
    ...
```

Thank you very much in advance,

Juan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I should be going with the approach that I laid out above. The answer is in the following thread.

[spring jms error handler access to message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085662/spring-jms-error-handler-access-to-message).